# Stop quantity spinner from going negative

Tags: jquery, spinner

I have a problem with a spinner. I want to stop the decrease function from working if the quantity is 0. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
      var elm = $('#htop');
              function spin( vl ) {
                elm.val( parseInt( elm.val(), 10 ) + vl );
              }

              $('#increase').click( function() { spin( 1 );  } );
              $('#decrease').click( function() { spin( -1 ); } );
    });
```

I am guessing I need to do something with the

```
$('#decrease').click( function() { spin( -1 ); } );
```

or maybe I should try wrapping an if statement around

```
function spin( vl ) {
                elm.val( parseInt( elm.val(), 10 ) + vl );
              }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stop the decrease function from working if the quantity is 0`

Just turn this in to code and you'll be fine:

```
function spin( vl ) {
    if(elm.val() > 0) { //as long as the spinner is above 0
        elm.val( parseInt( elm.val(), 10 ) + vl );
    }
}
```

Comment: This works unless some smart customer decides to push the subtract button first, then they are stuck on 0. It's a good start, I'll play around with it some more then.

Comment: I have it working with $('#decrease').click( function() { if (elm.val () > 0 ){spin( -1 ); } }); Can you see any problems with this?